# Directory.GetFiles error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

my code

```
private void m1()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles("a1"))
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(str).Contains("txt")) -- get all txt file in a1 folder
        {
            list.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str));
        }
    }

    base.SuspendLayout();
    this.Combobox_1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
    base.ResumeLayout();
}
```

but combobox cannot list txt file in folder a1
Please helpme.

Comment: Did you make sure that the relative path to "a1" is correct?

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? Or is the combo box just not being loaded?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "but combobox cannot list txt file in folder a1"? What happens?

Comment: You could use a debugger to check if `list` is at least populated...

Comment: a1 folder should be in the working directory of the executing process. This is the same folder your executable is in when you start your executable by double clicking or by F5 or CTRL + F5. Is it? You can check the actual location with string fullPathToA1Folder = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("a1");

Comment: "a1" is subfolder in directory and this code auto detects directory

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9uuKlFp.jpg

Comment: Have you read about parameter of [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) ? Namely this part: *"The path parameter can specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory"*...

Comment: In C#, the syntax for inline comments is // or /* .. */, and not -- by the way.. From your image, it can be seen that the drop down list is empty. Yes.

Comment: The string.Contains() method is case sensitive. Can your text files have an extension like *.TXT? Why don't you just change the GetFiles to Directory.GetFiles("a1", "\*.txt"); which will look for files with the extension .txt case insensitively?

Comment: And you can then remove the inner if condition. - if (Path.GetExtension(str).Contains("txt"))

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul
Yes. And i want show all txt file in "a1" folder in the drop down list

Comment: Yes, then just do Directory.GetFiles("a1", "\*.txt") and remove the obsolete if condition inside ( remove if (Path.GetExtension(str).Contains("txt")) )

Comment: I tried but it failed. Please help me fix it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no need to store values first in a list and then add to a combobox.
it can be done directly to a combobox.

i have replace relative path a1 to a real one to let you understand easily.

```
foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\")) 
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(str).Contains("txt"))
                {
                    this.Combobox_1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str));
                }
            }
```